# Update from select MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying update the amount between "%2017-08-01%" and 
"%2017-08-07%" to the amount from the next date "%2017-08-07%" where the e.auto="true" in the transaction table. However, the mysql is returning

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM user as u JOIN e_wallet as e ON e.id =
>   u.ewallet JOIN transacti' at line 1

```
update t set t.amount = (
                          select t.amount 
                          FROM user as u 
                          JOIN e_wallet as e ON e.id = u.ewallet 
                          JOIN transaction as t on t.user = u.id 
                          where e.auto="true" 
                                and t.create_date like "%2017-08-07%"
                        ) 
FROM user as u 
JOIN e_wallet as e ON e.id = u.ewallet 
JOIN transaction as t on t.user = u.id 
where e.auto="true" 
      and t.create_date BETWEEN "%2017-08-01%" and "%2017-08-07%"
```

Comment: `%2017-08-01%"` isn't a date. It's a string that contains something that looks like a date between `%` characters

Comment: `BETWEEN` can't be used with wildcard characters (`%`). It's designed for dates and numbers, not for strings.

Comment: @diiN__________ it works with strings that contain dates as well. This string though doesn't contain a valid date. I suspect there's a different error though. Once it's fixed, the next one will be about the date literals. Or **worse**, the query will work without producing results

Comment: Ok that was my bad, but my query still return the same error

Comment: @JohnWick read the error and look for the syntax error it mentions in the place mentioned. We are busy trying to format that long string into a query

Comment: @JohnWick in the meantime, if you can't understand exactly where the error is,  extract *parts* of the query and check that they work.

Comment: It still returns the same error 1064, starting from the "From user" line. Even the select query inside the bracket is working, but right after the bracket, it returns an error

Comment: Everything after the bracket, ) FROM user as u -> this part is not working properly. But the query within the bracket is almost the same as the one outside

Comment: And both are weird. The inner query will return *multiple* values unless there is only a single transaction per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the subquery, your `UPDATE` query looks like:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.amount = ...
FROM user AS u ...
JOIN e_wallet AS e ...
```

You can't have a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` query, and that's what's causing the syntax error. The syntax is:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
JOIN tablename2 AS t2 ON ...
JOIN tablename3 AS t3 ON ...
SET ...
WHERE ...
```

So it should be:

```
UPDATE transaction AS t
JOIN user AS u ON u.id = t.user
JOIN e_wallet AS e ON e.id = u.ewallet
SET t.amount = (
  select t.amount 
  FROM user as u 
  JOIN e_wallet as e ON e.id = u.ewallet 
  JOIN transaction as t on t.user = u.id 
  where e.auto="true" 
        and t.create_date like "%2017-08-07%"
) 
WHERE e.auto = "true"
AND t.create_date BETWEEN "2017-08-01" and "2017-08-07"
```

This should solve the syntax error, but I'm not sure it will do what you want. The subquery isn't correlated with the main query, so it will return the amounts of all transactions that meet the criteria. But when you use a subquery as an expression it has to return at most one row. You probably just want to join with the `transaction` table a second time.

```
UPDATE transaction AS t
JOIN user AS u ON u.id = t.user
JOIN e_wallet AS e ON e.id = u.ewallet
JOIN transaction AS t1 ON t1.user = t.user
SET t.amount = t1.amount
WHERE e.auto = "true"
AND t.create_date BETWEEN "2017-08-01" and "2017-08-07"
AND t1.create_date LIKE '%2017-08-07%'
```

Comment: Your query is a lot simpler than I thought, didnt know we could actually simplify it that way